# file -b command return on sticky bit files

Tags: linux, files, directory

I am trying to understand why the `file -b` command is returning a certain value(s) when the sticky bit is set.

When I run `file -b <dir>` where `dir` has its group set to `g+wrs`, `file -b` returns `setgid directory`. Is this an expected output and how can I make it so it does not return setgid even on sticky bit directories?

To add more information it appears that this is happening to all directories that have their sticky bit set for the group.

Additionally, yes I have read the man page.

Comment: `how can I make it so it does not return setgid even on sticky bit directories?` – What's the point? [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) maybe? To tell if some path leads to a directory check the exit status of `test -d /the/path`.

Answer (score 1):

The 's' bit *for user* (04000) is `setuid`.

The 's' bit *for group* (02000) is `setgid`.

The 't' bit _for *other* (01000) is `sticky`.

You set the 's' bit for group which is `setgid` and is not `sticky`.

To set the `sticky` bit set `o+t` or something including that as a subset.